# Session->flash is not showing session message in CakePHP

Tags: session, cakephp, flash-message, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.x

I'm using CakePHP 2.6.7 and copied the code to show flash messages from one controller to another, but it's not working in the second controller.

In AdminsController:

```
   function login() {
        $this->loadModel('Admin');
        $this->layout = "admin-login";
        // if already logged in check this step
        if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            return $this->redirect('dashboard'); //(array('action' => 'deshboard'));
        }
        // after submit login form check this step
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                // pr($this->Auth); exit;
                if ($this->Auth->user('status') == 'active') {
                    // user is activated
                    $this->Admin->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
                    $this->Admin->saveField("loggedIn", 1);
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
                } else {
                    // user is not activated
                    // log the user out
                    $msg = '<div class="alert alert-error">
                           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                           <strong>You are blocked, Contact with Adminstrator</strong>
                        </div>';
                    $this->Session->setFlash($msg);
                    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
                }
            } else {
                $msg = '<div class="alert alert-error">
                           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                           <strong>Incorrect email/password combination. Try Again</strong>
                        </div>';
                $this->Session->setFlash($msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

In admins/login.ctp:

```
<?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

When I type wrong email or password it shows error message. 
proof: http://jegeachi.com/admins/login

But SAME task cannot be done in ResellersController. Here is the controller code:

```
function login() {
    $this->layout = 'public-login';
    $this->loadModel('Reseller');
        // if already logged in check this step
    if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {
            return $this->redirect('profile'); //(array('action' => 'deshboard'));
        }
        // after submit login form check this step
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->Auth->login()) {

                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            } else {

                $msg = '<div class="alert alert-error">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>Incorrect email/password combination. Try Again</strong>
            </div>';
            $this->Session->setFlash($msg);

        }
    }
}
```

in Resellers/login.ctp:

```
 <?php echo $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

When login failed due to wrong email or password it is not being showed.

proof: http://jegeachi.com/resellers/login

Its a strange and wired problem. Same code work in a controller but not in other. Any idea?

Comment: I am using cakephp 2.6.7 and load Session in both admins controller and resellers controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are not already consuming the Session flash message.
This could happen if you have in your `app/View/Layouts/public-login.ctp` layout something like:

```
<?php $this->Session->flash(); ?>
```

Or somewhere in your view/view blocks.

---

Checking the HTML output, I have found the following instead of the expected error message:

```
    <div class="alert alert-danger display-hide">
        <button class="close" data-close="alert"></button>
        <span> Enter Email and password. </span>
    </div>
```

Check your `beforeRender()` callback and make sure you are not flashing the above message. If you are, it's overwriting the previous one.

Comment: I checked and strange is: I download all files into my local pc. Session message is being showed in my localhost. Its really frustrating.

Comment: All I'm getting now is blank page with the 'wrong' message.

Comment: I just tried with echo 'wrong'; exit; for testing. Now I edit my code as above. Now you can see no flash message with wrong email password.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I think you have forgot to echo your session message 
please write like below
In your ctp file

```
echo $this->Session->flash();
```